# I can not get request in body format in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I have problems receiving request in body format on my server.

I am using ***Express version 4.17.1.*** The documentation indicates that I don't have to use body-parserer, but I can do it directly with the express functionality "express.json ()"

However, I've been trying to get it to work for a long time but nothing happens: the console does not show anything. It seems that it does not recognize the request at all.

I'm doing all the request from Postman in body format JSON.

This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const formidable = require("express-formidable");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(formidable());
app.use(cors());

(...)

app.post("/list", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your time and help in advance.

Comment: The problem is probably in the code making the request from the other end, specifically it probably isn't setting the `Content-Type` of the request correctly. Please show that code.

Answer (score 0):

Express parse request body according to defined type in `Content-Type` header. Try to do request with header `Content-Type: application/json`.